# Managing a large 3D array that is worked with often

Tags: java, arrays, 3d

I'm trying to make a videogame. A randomly generated world made of 3D blocks, and with various creatures inhabiting it. Simple 2D graphics, tick-based time. I tried to generate a simple testing world like this:

```
        World currentWorld = new World(24576, 24576, 150);

    for (int ix = 0; ix < currentWorld.worldArray.length; ix++) {
        for (int iy = 0; iy < currentWorld.worldArray[0].length; iy++) {
            for (int iz = 0; iz < currentWorld.worldArray[0][0].length; iz++) {
                currentWorld.worldArray[ix][iy][iz] = new Element(random.nextInt(10));
                System.out.println(currentWorld.worldArray[ix][iy][iz].ID);
            }
        }
    }
```

And I got this error:

`Exception in thread "Display" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at cz.sargon.realms.world.World.<init>(World.java:11)`

I understand that the error means that I ran out of Java's 'working' memory, intended for tempopary storage of data that is currently being worked with. Now, how do I go around storing this world somehow and working with it later? I will need to read from it every time I want to render something and also check the AIs of some of the creatures every few ticks (I plan for every creature in the world to check it's surroundings every few ticks and react in an appropriate way to its circumstances).

Comment: Dont load the entire world to memory, load as needed

Comment: I suppose that would help, but how exactly do I do that in code?

Comment: More of a design problem really, do you need to keep the entire world in memory?

Comment: Not really, no. I only need to read what's needed for rendering graphics on the screen(the stuff around the player, about 5000 tiles max) and then I'll need to check the surroundings of all mobs in the world(not necessarily checking every mob every tick) so that their AI can do something. And of course I'll need to update the world every tick. My problem is that I don't know the exact technical solution to creating such a world without running out of memory.